# How to choose all details of the contact saved in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

As far as I know we can choose `Address`, `Email`, and `Phone Number` of the peoples added in our windows phone device using `AddressChooserTask`, `EmailAddressChooserTask` and `PhoneNumberChooserTask` respectively. What I want is to access all the persons details in one just single task. How can I do that. It is possible or not?

Regards
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer...

using UserData namespace and Contacts Class, we can do it like this..

```
Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts contact = new Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts();
contact.SearchCompleted += contact_SearchCompleted;
contact.SearchAsync("",Microsoft.Phone.UserData.FilterKind.None,"");
```